# MySql: how to make subquery and count all rows where id is the same in two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

How to make a query which return values for specific ID's not for all.

```
    SELECT content.id, count(case likes.type when 'p' then 1 else null end) as p
FROM content
JOIN likes on likes.content_id = content.id
```

this code returns:

```
ID p
1 18
```

but i want it:

```
ID p
1 12
2 4
3 2
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Where_%28SQL%29 It astonishes me that you know sql well enough to do a joined query, but know it so poorly you've never heard of how to use a `where` clause.

Comment: Then add `group by content.id`.

Answer (score 1):

Add a `group by`

```
SELECT content.id, 
       sum(likes.type = 'p') as p
FROM content
JOIN likes on likes.content_id = content.id
GROUP BY content.id
```

Then the aggregate functions (i.e. `count()`) are applied to the groups and not to the whole result.

Answer (score 1):

You query would fail in most databases.  The problem is that `content.id` is not summarized in the `select` but you are using an aggregation function.

This is a simple problem to fix:

```
SELECT content.id, count(case likes.type when 'p' then 1 else null end) as p
FROM content
JOIN likes on likes.content_id = content.id
GROUP BY content.id;
```

However, in general, you should be careful and *always* include all non-aggregated columns in the `select` in a `group by`.